# warning: unused variable 'a' [-Wunused-variable] en arreglo

Tags: c, array

El programa tiene que mostrar la cantidad de elementos que componen el arreglo
compila y da bien el resultado pero aparece esta advertencia

```
warning: unused variable 'a' [-Wunused-variable]
```

El error puede deberse a que no se muestra el arreglo, pero a mi no me interesa mostrar el arreglo, solo su cantidad de elementos. ¿Hay alguna forma de corregir esa advertencia sin mostrar el arreglo?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#define TAMANIO 12

/* la función main comienza la ejecución del programa */
int main()
{
    /* utiliza una lista de inicialización para inicializar el arreglo */
    int a[] = { 1, 3, 5, 4, 7, 2, 99, 16, 45, 67, 89, 45 };
    int i; /* contador */        
    int total = 0; /* inicialización de la variable total */
    
    /* suma el contenido del arreglo a */
    for ( i = 0; i < TAMANIO; i++ ) {
        total += 1;
    } /* fin de for */
    
    printf( "El total de los elementos del arreglo es %d\n", total );
    return 0; /* indica terminación exitosa */
    getch();
    
} /* fin de main */
```

Comment: No tiene nada que ver con que no se muestre el arreglo, el problema es que no lo usas para nada. Borra la declaración de `a`, o úsala para algo.

Comment: ¿Y ese algo que es?

Comment: Lo que sea que quieras hacer que `a`. La declaras y luego no usas la variable para nada.

Comment: No me estás entendiendo. a es el nombre del arreglo. Lo que está pidiendo es mostrarlo, pero no quiero mostrarlo

Comment: Te entiendo perfectamente. ¿Para qué usas `a`? ¿Qué pasa con el programa si eliminas `a`?

Comment: En realidad no hace nada con esa variable y es la pedo lo que declara, el valor de total siempre será igual al valor de TAMANIO

Comment: Si el valor es igual al de TAMANIO, pero si pongo int [TAMANIO]; tira error (error: expected identifier or '(' before '[' token)

Answer (score -2):

La advertencia se debe a que no se muestra ni se usa el arreglo. Simplemente se cuentan números dentro del for hasta la constante 12 y se muestran, y con eso el arreglo no tiene nada que ver.

La forma de corregir esto es eliminar la variable TAMANIO y en el for sustuirla por una expresión que determine el final de un arreglo, en ese caso que en el recorrido el valor `i` quede distinto al de `a[i]`

El programa completo quedaría así:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>

/* la función main comienza la ejecución del programa */
int main()
{
    /* utiliza una lista de inicialización para inicializar el arreglo */
    int a[] = { 1, 3, 5, 4, 7, 2, 99, 16, 45, 67, 89, 45 };
    int i; /* contador */
    int total = 0; /* inicialización de la variable total */

    /* suma el contenido del arreglo a */
    for ( i = 0; i != a[i]; i++ ) {
        total += 1;
    } /* fin de for */

    printf( "El total de los elementos del arreglo es %d\n", total );
    return 0; /* indica terminación exitosa */
    getch();
    

} /* fin de main */
```

Comment: Error. La advertencia se debe, como te han comentado, a que declaras una variable y luego no la usas en ningun sitio. Al compilador le da absolutamente igual si vas a mostrar un arreglo o no... el solo mira (en este caso que nos ocupa) que las variables declaradas se usen para algo... es como comprarte un coche y no hacerle ni un solo kilómetro... un absurdo.